# Unit Test return expired JWT tokens [Laravel 5.2]

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, jwt

I use Tymon JWT pkg, problem is It always in return in response:
Token has expired.

Here is the test:

```
public function test_store_games()
    {

           $token = Auth::tokenById(1);

        $response = $this->post(Config::get('settings.api') . 'games', [
            'name' => 'test123',
            'category' => 'test'],['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);

        $this->assertRequestOk();
    }
```

Var `$token` generate toke I tested but it always expired... Anyone know what is problem?

Answer (score 1):

Does this change anything if you add it to your controller?

```
function __construct()
    {
        // for testing only, otherwise JWTAuth::parseToken() fails
        if (env('APP_ENV') == 'testing' 
                && array_key_exists("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", request()->server())) {
            JWTAuth::setRequest(\Route::getCurrentRequest());
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set expiry date in jwt.php config file 
 **'ttl' => 60**   . By defaultits 1 hour change it to increase time.